# Kohana $this->request->param('id') - what is it used for - GET or POST

Tags: kohana

I'm new to Kohana. It is used this:
`$this->request->param('id')`
when should I use it - it means POST or GET?
When could I use it - how to pass parameters when they are $_POST or $_GET data?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both POST and GET in fact are not true.
For POST you will use:

```
$this->request->post();
```

For GET you will use:

```
$this->request->query();
```

That what you are asking:

```
$this->request->param('id')
```

is used if you want to get route id parameter.

Read about routes here:
https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing

Comment: Well, so if it is route id parameter, isn't it get? It is in URL, it's not POST, it might be GET? :)

Comment: Nope, for ex.: test.com/articles/edit/2 - using standard Kohana route '2' will be id here, so nothing here to perform GET. But if you will add, for ex.: test.com/articles/edit/2?update_date=true - then you can perform GET operation to access update_date param. Route parameters and GET parameters are different things. Hope you get it now :)

Comment: Thanks for explanation!